# Reactjs how to lazy load image in a div component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, lazy-loading, styled-components

I need to find a way to apply the Lazy plugin in the code below, would it be possible?
I thank you for your help!

**styled-components**
**==================**

```
import styled from "styled-components";
import { LazyLoadImage } from "react-lazy-load-image-component";
import "react-lazy-load-image-component/src/effects/blur.css";

export const Container = styled.div`
  position: relative;
  background-color: #191925;
  background-image: url(${props => props.src});
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: left;
  }
`;
```

**ReacJS
=================**

```
import React from "react";
import { Container} from "./styles";

function Banner({
  backgroundImg = "",
  title = "",
  subtitle = "",
  tag = "",
  description = "",
  price,
  dark,
}) {
  return (
    <Container src={backgroundImg}>
      
    </Container>
  );
}

export default Banner;
```

Comment: You are already using lazy loading, the browser will only load the img if it is on the viewport https://web.dev/lazy-loading-images/